# Hibernate get max value

Tags: hibernate

I want to get max value of column from table.

This is SQL query I want to execute using Hibernate:

```
String max = //SELECT MAX(column_string) FROM table;
```

But I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT MAX(column_string) FROM table");
String max = query.getSingleResult();
```